# Javascript reduce() to find the shortest word in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have a function that finds the longest word in a string.

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longest = str.split(' ').reduce((longestWord, currentWord) =>{
    return currentWord.length > longestWord.length ? currentWord : longestWord;
  }, "");
  return longest;
}
console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

I'm having a hard time converting this to find the shortest word. Why can't I just change `currentWord.length > longestWord.length` to `currentWord.length < longestWord.length`?

Comment: The problem is the initial value `""`. You'll never find a word shorter than that.

Comment: ah ok, yes that makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide an initial value to the `reduce` function, otherwise a blank string is the shortest word:

```js
function findShortestWord(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var shortest = words.reduce((shortestWord, currentWord) => {
    return currentWord.length < shortestWord.length ? currentWord : shortestWord;
  }, words[0]);
  return shortest;
}
console.log(findShortestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Answer (score 2):

While using `reduce`, `initialValue` is optional and if it isn't provided then your first element will be used as `initialValue`. So, in your case, you'll just have to remove your `""`:

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longest = (typeof str == 'string'? str : '')
    .split(' ').reduce((longestWord, currentWord) =>{
      return currentWord.length < longestWord.length ? currentWord : longestWord;
  });
  return longest;
}
console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")); // The
```

Comment: Worth noting that if no value passed is not a string (e.g. no value at all, null, etc.) this will throw an error, so best to include a test to make sure there's an argument that's a string (even an empty string will do), e.g. `var longest = (typeof str == 'string'? str : '').split(...`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I coded it in this way

```js
const findLongestWord = str => {
  return typeof str === 'string' 
  ? str.split(' ').reduce((sw, lw) => lw.length < sw.length ? lw :sw)
  : '';
}
console.log(findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')); //'The'
```